# How to get a single defined element of a Coproduct instance?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'll be concise:

```
val pvSchema = RecordType.like(
  's  ->> "" ::
  'l  ->> Long.MaxValue ::
  HNil
)

type PossibleValue = pvSchema.Union

val v = Coproduct[PossibleValue]('s -> "string")
```

To get `Some[String]` I could use `v.get('s)`, while `v.get('i)` returns me `None`. Can I somehow do `v.unconditionalGet()` to get the defined value without checking for all other possibilities?

Comment: What would you expect the result type of `v.unconditionalGet` to be?

Comment: @Miles, I got it. I actually was mapping `Coproduct` to a pair `(String, String)` or `(Int, String)` and I realized that I'm interested only in the second part of the tuple, so I've just rewritten that part. Anyway, I love it when questions in comments answer the question :)

Comment: Would it be correct if I delete the question?

Comment: @cdshines: I'd say instead of deleting you should answer the question yourself, explaining what you figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that my question was a bit incorrect to start with. Since we deal with the union type, getting some result without knowing it's type beforehand becomes kind of a nonsense: one can't use that result safely. E.g.:

```
// suppose this is what I want
val value = v.getPresent()

use(value)
```

Here `use` should be able to handle both `String` and `Int`, and least upper bound for that is something like `Any`, and that means no desired type safety again.

I've somewhat reconsidered my design and everything works fine now.